# kill rectangle not working on Mac (missing file/library)

Tags: osx, rectangle, kill-text

I just upgraded to emacs 26.2 using homebrew on my MAC (update: I had actually done a global "brew update" and assumed it had also updated emacs) and now kill-rectangle with 
`C-x r k` no longer works, and instead gives me an error:

```
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, rect
```

Any idea how I can get it back as it is a super useful feature...

Comment: `rect` is part of Emacs, so the fact that your computer can't see it suggests that there was either an error in installation, or else there were additional things you needed to install.  That's probably more of a homebrew issue than an Emacs issue per se, but maybe some mac users can explain better.

Comment: Two things to try: `C-h k C-x r k` to see what command that key chord is running. (For me I get `C-x r k runs the command kill-rectangle`). Then try `C-h f kill-rectangle` to see the documentation for that command, which should tell you what the associated keybinding is.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with `emacs -Q`?

Answer (score 1):

Comments on the question post made me understand that the `rect` library was missing.  I looked into brew and tried a

```
brew upgrade emacs
```

and surprise surprise it told me that emacs was not installed, so it seems that my emacs was a default "build in" prior to me switching to use homebrew and my global **brew upgrade** command had not actually upgraded emacs but instead had somehow messed up the syncing of library versions.

```
brew install emacs
```

installed v26.3 and was all I needed to put things right.

Comment: This one is kind of on the fence about whether it is about Emacs per se or about the Mac, but it seems like this could be something that other Emacs users will run into.  I'm inclined to say keep the question and answer post.  Go ahead and accept your own answer as soon as the system lets you.

Comment: okay and thanks for your improvements with the edits and help with the question